# Does the electricity meter move at a different speed depending on how many appliances are being used?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I was wondering if it could be used as an economy measure to wash, vacuum, etc. at the same time rather than at different times of the day.

Comment: You are charged by the kilowatt hour used if you use a kilowatt in one day or 19 days the cost is the same. Some power suppliers offer lower per kw rate during off peak times. That is why a timer on a big power user like a water heater can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The meter's speed is determined by current flow, so it moves faster or slower depending on electrical consumption.

What may change at different times of the day is the price per unit of electricity. So don't worry about meter speed, check with your utility supplier to determine what time of day would be most economical to consume the most.

Comment: As a UK poster, the Economy7 tariff (cheap rate from 11pm to 7-ish am) wouldn't work for me - I have gas water and central heating and gas cooker.  My current tariff is 1 kWh at 16.19p.  Power shower, telly, lights and laptop are the only normal daily use electrical items, the only other big thing is the washing machine.

Comment: I had the idea that as I vacuumed then showered while the washer was on, it might save a bit.

Comment: Probably not, unless you do it during a time period when *rates* (money/unit cost) are reduced. Conversely, if you do it during peak usage hours (a time when *rates* are often inflated) you may very well pay more in the end.

Answer (score 1):

There are three factors in an electricity bill (beyond taxes and miscellaneous fees):

1. Usage = price per kilowatt hour (kWh)
2. Demand = price per kilowatt demand (kW) = a price based on the time when you are using the most kilowatts - i.e., the most electricity at one specific time. Typically measured over 15-minute intervals and billed based on the highest 15-minute or 30-minute (consecutive intervals averaged).
3. Time-of-day - The Usage rates may vary depending on the time of day (weekday daytime highest, morning/evening lower, nights/weekends lowest) and the Demand charge may be based on the peak demand of the highest usage category (i.e., only of weekday daytime - if your peak demand is at night then it doesn't count towards your bill)

Modern smart meters can easily track all this information and, typically, will report back to the utility the usage & demand for each 15-minute interval - i.e., 192 values per day (96 demand, 96 usage). They may also report lots of other information (voltage, current, frequency, power factor, etc.) but most of the other information has no effect on your bill.

In most areas (at least in the USA), demand charges and time-of-day usage charges are only applied to commercial accounts and not to residential accounts. My take on that is that there is a perception by users that charges for demand or for time-of-day usage are "unfair". They actually can represent real charges to the utility - and in that sense are quite "fair" to the customers in representing actual costs to the utility, though there is always some question as to how much of the costs, particularly with respect to demand charges, are "real". A utility generally pays the most for the highest demand period when the always-on (hydro, nuclear, etc.) power sources are not enough and additional generators are needed (e.g., natural gas). There are also infrastructure charges which are related to the highest possible demand.

In many areas, in addition to time-of-use not even being reported to residential users (let alone charged at different rates), usage charges are often at the same rate for on-peak vs. off-peak for commercial users.

End result: Check your utility bill. If you have different rates for on-peak/off-peak OR if you have a Demand Charge (it will show a calculation based on kW, not kWh) then you will typically benefit from running high-usage appliances at night to get the lower off-peak rate and/or to keep the peak demand as low as possible. If you don't have either of these then it makes no difference when you use your appliances.

Comment: Good answer I had the feeling OP was thinking of electric usage like gas mileage in a car. 100 mph gets you far fewer miles per gallon. but multitasking with home appliances is not more expensive than doing a task at a time right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, usually on old analogue meters with only a single row of numbers, time of day isn't taken into account, so use all the energy you need when you need and the price will be the same Ex: you can use a 3kW appliance for 20 minutes or a 1 kW appliance for one hour and you'll be charged for a unit.   Business connections are also charged for reactive power (a phantom power that has to be delivered but that is not turned into work). Other fees here includes: dispatching, power-rate (we are charged differently for different power available, most common rate used for home is 3kW), Other fees: nuclear decommissioning, renewable power incentives, poor people help, railway, TV tax, excises and VAT.

Here (Italy), we're on electronic meters and we may have a 'mono-tier' tariff so we pay the same rate all day round, a bi-tier tariff and we have different rates (actually very similar) for on-peak tier F1 (8:00-19:00 mon-fri) and off-peak tier F23 (19:00-8:00 mo,n-fri, h24 sat+sun) and a tri-tier tariff similar to 2-hour but with F2 tier counted on it's own F2 (07:00-08:00, 19:00-23-00 mon-fri , 07:00-23:00 sat). First two are common for home connections, the latter is for commercial.

Answer (score 0):

An old spinning-disc meter won't do any of the fancy rate tricks like peak surge, time-of-day, discounts etc.  So we can exclude those.

The meter records accurately *the energy you actually use*.  **There's no free lunch.** There isn't a way to "game the meter" to get power cheaper by running any combination of appliances in particular ways.

Now if you ever get on a different rate plan (necessitating a smart meter) then things like time-of-day, peak energy flow, things like that will start to matter.